# webrtc leaks audio played on other tabs

Tags: javascript, webrtc, easyrtc, simplewebrtc

when i'm in a video call with someone else, and listen to a youtube music on another tab at the same time, that person can hear it crystal clear.

BTW i'm using a headphone, so there's no way sound is from my speaker. I'm on Mac using Chrome.

Why does this happen, and is there a way to turn other sounds off?

Comment: sounds like the kind of problem waiting 6 weeks will fix... or maybe your recording mixer is allowing more than just mic?

Comment: What device are you sharing?

Comment: @AdrianBer Built-in microphone and facetime camera